# Значение чекбоксов записать в строку

Tags: php, html

Есть несколько checkbox'ов принадлежащих к имени Category и подающих разные значения. Как мне записать значения всех выбранных checkbox'ов в строку через запятую?

```
<span>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="men">men</div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="female">female</div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="a1">a1</div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="a2">a2</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="men">men</div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="female">female</div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="a1">a1</div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="a2">a2</div>
</span>
```

php

```
implode(',', $_POST['category']);
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что он не создает массив, а задает значение последнего выбранного элемента

Comment: @dmitriy kiryushin повнимательней посмотрите мой пост.

Comment: Благодарю за столь нужный ответ)